# Using Async/Await correctly in VB

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous

I am having trouble getting a datatable from a WCF service using Async/Await and loading it into a datagridview. This is my first time doing this, I feel like I am missing something basic. This is the code I have so far:

```
Private p_oDataService As New SQLService.DataServiceClient

Async Function GetReportDataTable() As Task(Of DataTable)
  Try
    p_oDataService = New SQLService.DataServiceClient
    Dim tDatatable As Task(Of DataTable) = p_oDataService.GetValidationReportsAsync()
    Dim dt As DataTable = Await tDatatable
    Return dt
  Catch ex As Exception
    Throw ex
  End Try
End Function 

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  Try
    Dim tDT As Task(Of DataTable) = GetReportDataTable()
    Dim dt As DataTable = GetReportDataTable.Result
    DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = True
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
  Catch ex As Exception
    Throw ex
  End Try
End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are mixing blocking and async calls. When you call `GetReportDataTable.Result` it will deadlock.

Event handlers allow you to await async tasks as well so update the event handler...

```
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
      Dim dt As DataTable = Await GetReportDataTable()
      DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = True
      DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    Catch ex As Exception
      Throw ex
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you.. my issue was that I didn't consider making the Button1_Click sub Async. Gracias